# What is the purpose of these purple images in these sprite files of Super Mario Maker?

Tags: 2d, graphics, sprites, spritesheet

I was looking at the Wii U's Super Mario Maker Sprites and noted that all of them have purple images that each correspond to one of the animation frames (see below). What could they have been used for? Why not simply using the finished colored ones?

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about how or why a specific game implemented a specific technique are not considered on-topic here.

Comment: That said, they look like normal maps; I would guess they were used to dynamically light the sprite in some fashion or otherwise give it the appearance of depth in a way that responds to the active environment around it (and thus that cannot be drawn into the sprite itself).